# align edit text with another edittext in another layout

Tags: android, alignment, siblings

how can I align edit text with another editText in different layouts?
(I got this error @+id/plastering_material_spinner is not a sibling in the same RelativeLayout 
Layout constraints in a given RelativeLayout should reference other views within the same relative layout (but not itself!))

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/image_Dead_Load"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_border"
    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
    android:paddingRight="6dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wall_material"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/material_thickness"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginEnd="91dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="110dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5sp"
        android:text="نوع مصالح"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/material_thickness"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="5sp"
        android:text="ضخامت mm"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/brick_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/material_thickness"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_wall_width"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/wall_material_spinner"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/wall_material_spinner"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/textinputborder"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:paddingLeft="5sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/wall_material_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/brick_material"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText_wall_width"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/brick_material"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/brick_material"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/wall_material_spinner"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="نوع آجر"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_heavy"
            android:textSize="15sp" />


    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/plastering_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/brick_layout">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_plastering_material"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/plastering_material_spinner"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/plastering_material_spinner"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/textinputborder"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:paddingLeft="5sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/plastering_material_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/plastering_material"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText_plastering_material"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/plastering_material"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/plastering_material"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/plastering_material_spinner"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:paddingLeft="5sp"
            android:text="نوع اندود"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_heavy"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: As the error states - you can't. But there are ways to align, show us some code if you want help!

Comment: some codes added... I want alignRight  "@+id/wall_material_spinner" with "@+id/plastering_material_spinner"

Comment: Element RelativeLayout (first One) is not closed

Comment: it is not all of my code, the tag is closed at the end of my code.anyway... if I add  ' android:layout_alignRight="@+id/plastering_material_spinner"' ' in first spinner tag I get the error.